# Cannot select markers with Leaflet and Leaflet knn plugin

Tags: leaflet

I'm getting a bunch of lat/lng from a database, loop through them and place the markers on the map.

```
let geoJson = []

for (let i in elements) {
  let element = elements[i],
    ll = L.latLng(element.Location[0], element.Location[1]),
    llArr = { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [element.Location[0], element.Location[1]] }

  geoJson.push(llArr) // to have a geoJson for nearest points

  L.marker(ll, { icon: createMarkerIcon(element.Category) }).on('click', function (e) {
    info.update({ name: element.Name, tu: element.ThumbsUp, td: element.ThumbsDown, id: element.Id, tags: generateTagsList(element.Tags) })
  }).addTo(map)
}
```

While doing this I'm also pushing the lat/lng to a geoJson to find the nearest marker of a location later on. Problem is that I am not able to select the `L.markers` put on the map before. It seems like the points in the geoJson are different elements than the markers.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like the points in the geoJson are different elements than the markers.

Yes you guessed right.

Furthermore, coordinates in GeoJSON format are expected to be in [longitude, latitude] order, whereas for Leaflet Markers it is [latitude, longitude] order.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Any idea how I can amend this piece of code to have the actual markers to be selectable?

Comment: Well, it is unclear to me what "selectable" means to you. If you could edit your question to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that would help people understand what you are trying to achieve.